# Limit with logarithm of zero

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim_{x\to\ 1^+} \frac{\log_{10}{(x-1)}}{\sqrt{x-1}}$$

Substituting $1$ in the function I get $\log_{10}{0}$ which doesn't exist. How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you allowed to use l'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @StackTD If there is no other solution then yes.

Comment: There are always alternatives; it depends on what you know and are allowed/supposed to use.

Comment: @StackTD I'm not allowed to use it when I'll take the exam so it's better if I don't use it as I'm preparing for the exam.

Comment: Is it $\log(x)-1$ or $\log(x-1)$ on the numerator ?

Comment: @zwim $\log(x-1)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\dfrac{\log_{10}(x-1)}{\sqrt{x-1}}=2\log_{10}e\lim_{x\to1^+}\dfrac{\ln\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}}$$

Let $\sqrt{x-1}=h\implies x-1=h^2$

$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\dfrac{\ln\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\ln h}h\to\infty$$

Comment: Why $$\lim_{x\to1^+}\dfrac{\log_{10}(x-1)}{\sqrt{x-1}}=2\log_{10}e\lim_{x\to1^+}\dfrac{\ln\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}}$$
?

Comment: @user556928, $$\log_ab=\log_ac\cdot\log_cb$$ right?

Comment: What is $c$????

Comment: @user556928, $a,b,c$ are arbitrary positive real variables

Comment: Could you write all the passages?